# how to remove particumar letter combination from a string in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string like below

```
he/a0h/a0dv/a0jks
```

I would like to be string become as below.

```
hehdvjks
```

Need to remove the "/a0" from the string.

Comment: A simple Google search can solve this for you.

Comment: look up string.Replace()

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var result = "he/a0h/a0dv/a0jks".Replace("/a0", string.Empty);
```

Comment: any reason for down voting?

Comment: Dunno why this was downvoted... seems like a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The String.Replace method is what you're looking for, just do a;

```
String myString = "he/a0h/a0dv/a0jks"
myString = myString.Replace("/a0", "")
```

It'll return a modified 'myString' with all occurrences of the old value ("/a0") replaced with a new value (blank in this case).

The MSDN reference for String.Replace can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx